# How to detect if Flash movie is visible in browser upon page load?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way using ActionScript to detect if the Flash movie is actually visible when the page loads with it on it. I need to determine if the SWF loads on the first visible page or it's below the fold, so the user needs to scroll down to see it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any built in way to handle this within Flash I don't believe the Stage has any awareness of it's position with regard to the laid out HTML.  My guess is you'll have to use something like this in Javascript http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html paired with ExternalInterface in Flex/Flash to communicate with some JavaScript that in turn looks for the position of the SPAN DIV or whatever the container is for your EMBED/OBJECT tags.